# Undefined Control Sequence section

Tags: templates, document-classes, texdef

I'm new to using LaTeX and I'm using someone else's template. I don't know but I keep getting Undefined Control Sequence error. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out in figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\lecture{\@ifnextchar[{\@lectureWith}{\@lectureWithout}}
\def\@lectureWith[#1]{\medbreak\refstepcounter{section}%
  \renewcommand{\leftmark}{Lecture \thesection}
  \noindent{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lecture \thesection: #1\@addpunct{.}}%
  \sectionfont Lecture \thesection. #1\@addpunct{.}}\medbreak}
\def\@lectureWithout{\medbreak\refstepcounter{section}%
  \renewcommand{\leftmark}{Lecture \thesection}
  \noindent{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lecture \thesection.}%
  \sectionfont Lecture \thesection.}\medbreak}
\makeatother

\title{Long Boring Lectures on 0-dimensional Manifolds}
\author{Alex Nelson}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lecture % it's ok for it to not take any arguments
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\lecture[I'M BRILLIANT] % It can also take an argument
At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis
praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas
molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et
harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum
soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime
placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.
 Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus
saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae.
Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
\end{document}
```

The error that I get is following:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@lectureWithout ...re \thesection .}\sectionfont 
                                                  Lecture \thesection .}\med...
l.23 L
      orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's never good to use someone else's code without understanding it. Unless they put it into a proper package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `article` class doesn't define `\sectionfont`, so you must provide a definition for it. Note that with that code a page break is quite good just after a lecture title. Don't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you're using doesn't define `\sectionfont` and the error message just says this.

However, that template is not very good, at least for one reason: a page break is *very* desirable, to LaTeX, just after a lecture title, because of `\medbreak`. Redefining `\leftmark` is not a good idea, either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

%%% this is the same as \@addpunct, but doesn't require \protect
\protected\def\addpunct#1{%
  \ifhmode\ifnum\spacefactor>1000 \else#1\fi\fi
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lecture}{ o }{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \markboth{Lecture \thesection\IfValueT{#1}{: #1\addpunct{.}}}{}%
  \section*{Lecture \thesection\IfValueT{#1}{: #1\addpunct{.}}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lecture \thesection\IfValueT{#1}{: #1\addpunct{.}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Long Boring Lectures on 0-dimensional Manifolds}
\author{Alex Nelson}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\lecture
% it's ok for it to not take any arguments
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\lecture[I'm brilliant] % It can also take an argument
At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis
praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas
molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et
harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum
soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime
placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.
 Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus
saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae.
Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.

\lecture[More brilliant!]
Again.
\end{document}
```

Note that `\addpunct` will not work with all caps titles, which are not typographically sound anyway.

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me how to add a sub section (sub lecture) to the main lecture? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AdityaGore Just do the same with `\subsection` instead of `\section`. Omit the `\markboth` setting, of course.