# Undefined control sequence in sections and subsections

Tags: sectioning, undefined

I'm new to LaTex and writing my first paper. For some reason a lot of my sections and subsections have the following error:

[image]

My code is quite long so I'm not sure which lines to share other than this one, but from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157338/undefined-control-sequence-section) SO question I believe that the document type is important. Mine is:

```
\documentclass{article}
```

And the rest of the packages are

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[section]{placeins}
% \usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\let\Oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection}
\let\Oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsection}
\let\Oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsubsection}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage {hyperref}
```

From one of the comments in the above SO question they mentioned "The article class doesn't define `\sectionfont`, so you must provide a definition for it". But I'm not sure what it means or how to define a font, as I'm new.

Comment: Did the publisher give you a template?

Comment: I don't have a publisher. I was planning on putting it on ArXiv

Comment: Then let me give you well-intended but generic advice: Maybe use an already existing template from a reputable publisher and do not try to micro-optimize this.

Comment: See here for example https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/academic-journal. The less complex the better.

Comment: Or https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/140133

Comment: Oh neat! Good idea. I'll take a look at it and try to convert it if I can't figure it out. I'm afraid that I will get more errors by changing

Comment: when asking about an error please always provide a test file that shows the error and also show the error message.  the screenshot just shows you have an error but does not show what that error is. The error message from TeX will show which command is undefined.

Comment: however you are using the command `\FloatBarrier` but that is defined by teheplaceins package that you appear to have commenetd out. If you are "new to latex" I could only advise not redefining core latex commands such as `\section`  (you can remov ethe whole block of `\let` and `\renewcommand` related to section also you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` unless you have a very old latex and you are specifying paclages twice (hyperref)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting as a complete test file:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[section]{placeins}
% \usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\let\Oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection}
\let\Oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsection}
\let\Oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsubsection}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage {hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{zzz}
zzz
\end{document}
```

You will see in the log the error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\section ->\FloatBarrier 
                         \Oldsection 
l.35 \section
             {zzz}
?
```

Showing that the undefined command is `\FloatBarrier` which you have not defined.

It is defined by the `placeins` package which is not loaded, but even if that package is used you should not redefine `\section` in this way. Simply use the `section` option, as is also shown commented out in your posting.

So the basic fix is to delete

```
\let\Oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection}
\let\Oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsection}
\let\Oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsubsection}
```

The example then runs without error.

You should also delete

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

unless you have an old latex

and delete

```
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
```

and

```
\usepackage {hyperref}
```

as you have already loaded those packages.